# eclipse cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, eclipse, export, drawable

Please help me export problem

```text
Please Help Me Eclipse Clean Problem dont signed apk
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
color cannot be resolved or is not a field  MapFragment.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments  line 320    Java Problem
color cannot be resolved or is not a field  MapFragment.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments  line 321    Java Problem
color cannot be resolved or is not a field  MapFragment.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments  line 322    Java Problem
color cannot be resolved or is not a field  UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 11 Java Problem
dimen cannot be resolved or is not a field  ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 258    Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 113    Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 431    Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   ImageViewerActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 40 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 55 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 141    Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 166    Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   MapFragment.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments  line 514    Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   MapFragment.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments  line 539    Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   MapFragment.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments  line 651    Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   MapFragment.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments  line 868    Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   NewReviewActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 51 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   NewsDetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 35 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 95 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   RegisterActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 77 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 60 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   SearchResultActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 56 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   StoreActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 56 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   TwitterDialog.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/social/twitter line 85 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 15 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 15 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 16 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 16 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 17 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 17 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 18 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 18 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 19 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 19 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 20 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 20 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 21 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 21 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 22 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 22 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 23 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 23 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 24 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 24 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 25 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 25 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 26 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 26 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 27 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 27 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 29 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 29 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 77 Java Problem
drawable cannot be resolved or is not a field   UIConfig.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 79 Java Problem
FacebookBroadcastReceiver cannot be resolved to a type  StoreFinderBroadcastReceiver.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/receiver   line 27 Java Problem
FacebookDialog cannot be resolved   DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 850    Java Problem
FacebookDialog cannot be resolved to a type DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 853    Java Problem
FacebookDialog cannot be resolved to a type DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 857    Java Problem
FacebookDialog cannot be resolved to a type DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 866    Java Problem
FacebookDialog cannot be resolved to a variable DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 851    Java Problem
FacebookException cannot be resolved to a type  DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 889    Java Problem
FeedDialogBuilder cannot be resolved to a type  DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 881    Java Problem
INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS cannot be resolved or is not a field  DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 1039   Java Problem
INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS cannot be resolved or is not a field  LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 349    Java Problem
INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS cannot be resolved or is not a field  MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 565    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field AboutUsFragment.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments  line 38 Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field AnimationFragment.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments  line 40 Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field CategoryFragment.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments  line 78 Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field CategoryFragment.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments  line 95 Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 162    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 315    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 390    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 453    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 486    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 491    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 492    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 493    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 494    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 496    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 499    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 502    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 507    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 509    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 512    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 515    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 518    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 521    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 524    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 527    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 530    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 585    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 608    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 612    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 638    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 642    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 646    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 650    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 665    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 674    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 678    Java Problem
id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 682    Java Problem
The method setActiveSession(Session) is undefined for the type Session  MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 572    Java Problem
The method openActiveSession(MainActivity, boolean, Session.StatusCallback) is undefined for the type Session   MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 580    Java Problem
The method onSuccessfulAppCall(String, String, Bundle) of type StoreFinderBroadcastReceiver must override or implement a supertype method   StoreFinderBroadcastReceiver.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/receiver   line 30 Java Problem
The method onFailedAppCall(String, String, Bundle) of type StoreFinderBroadcastReceiver must override or implement a supertype method   StoreFinderBroadcastReceiver.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/receiver   line 36 Java Problem
The method isOpened() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 721    Java Problem
The method isOpened() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 588    Java Problem
The method isOpened() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 575    Java Problem
The method isClosed() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 609    Java Problem
The method isClosed() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 575    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 720    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 608    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 587    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 567    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 557    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 538    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 537    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 528    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 527    Java Problem
The method executeAsync() is undefined for the type Request MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 658    Java Problem
The method closeAndClearTokenInformation() is undefined for the type Session    MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 610    Java Problem
The method call(Session, SessionState, Exception) of type MainActivity.SessionStatusCallback must override or implement a supertype method  MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 618    Java Problem
The import com.facebook.FacebookBroadcastReceiver cannot be resolved    StoreFinderBroadcastReceiver.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/receiver   line 21 Java Problem
The constructor Session(MainActivity) is undefined  MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 571    Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  RoundedImageView.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 86 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  RoundedImageView.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 85 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  RoundedImageView.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 80 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  RoundedImageView.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 70 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  RoundedImageView.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 69 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  RoundedImageView.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 61 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  RoundedImageView.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 59 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  MGImageView.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 84 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  MGImageView.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 83 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  MGImageView.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 78 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  MGImageView.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 68 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  MGImageView.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 67 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  MGImageView.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 59 Java Problem
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  MGImageView.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/imageview  line 57 Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field StoreActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 163    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field StoreActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 151    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field StoreActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 149    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field SearchResultActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 155    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field SearchResultActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 143    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field SearchResultActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 141    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 310    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 309    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 274    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 272    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 156    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 155    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 140    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 140    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field RegisterActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 286    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field RegisterActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 285    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 503    Java Problem
The method closeAndClearTokenInformation() is undefined for the type Session    ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 505    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field RegisterActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 274    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field RegisterActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 273    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field RegisterActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 250    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field RegisterActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 162    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field RegisterActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 161    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 483    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 473    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 472    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 471    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 168    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 167    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field MGUtilities.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/utilities  line 77 Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field MGUtilities.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/utilities  line 57 Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 197    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 198    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field LocationUtils.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/location   line 84 Java Problem
Session.OpenRequest cannot be resolved to a type    MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 576    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 214    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 215    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 316    Java Problem
Request.GraphUserCallback cannot be resolved to a type  MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 625    Java Problem
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field   StoreActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 209    Java Problem
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field   SearchResultActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 205    Java Problem
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field   ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 123    Java Problem
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field   RegisterActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 450    Java Problem
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field   ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 546    Java Problem
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field   MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 256    Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field SwipeRefreshActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/refreshlayout  line 33 Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field StoreActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 96 Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field StoreActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 52 Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field SearchResultActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 85 Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field NewsDetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 90 Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field NewsDetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 91 Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field SearchResultActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 49 Java Problem
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field   NewsDetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 141    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field NewReviewActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 82 Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 223    Java Problem
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field   NewReviewActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 113    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field NewReviewActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 133    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field NewReviewActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 134    Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field ReviewActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 56 Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field NewReviewActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 144    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field NewReviewActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 145    Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field RegisterActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 73 Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field ProfileActivity.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 81 Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field NewsDetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 31 Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field NewReviewActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 47 Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 421    Java Problem
string cannot be resolved or is not a field NewReviewActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 61 Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 335    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 342    Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java   /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder   line 138    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 351    Java Problem
The constructor Session(LoginActivity) is undefined LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 355    Java Problem
The method setActiveSession(Session) is undefined for the type Session  LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 356    Java Problem
The method isOpened() is undefined for the type Session LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 359    Java Problem
The method isClosed() is undefined for the type Session LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 359    Java Problem
Session.OpenRequest cannot be resolved to a type    LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 360    Java Problem
The method openActiveSession(LoginActivity, boolean, Session.StatusCallback) is undefined for the type Session  LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 364    Java Problem
The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type Session LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 370    Java Problem
The method isOpened() is undefined for the type Session LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 371    Java Problem
Request.GraphUserCallback cannot be resolved to a type  LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 379    Java Problem
The method executeAsync() is undefined for the type Request LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 404    Java Problem
The method call(Session, SessionState, Exception) of type LoginActivity.SessionStatusCallback must override or implement a supertype method LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 409    Java Problem
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field   LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 472    Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field MGUtilities.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/utilities  line 115    Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field MGUtilities.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/utilities  line 100    Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field MGUtilities.java    /StoreFinder/src/com/utilities  line 47 Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field LoginActivity.java  /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 51 Java Problem
```

Comment: Hi Joshgun, can you add a more descriptive question please? It's not clear at all from your current question what you are asking.

Comment: I'm doing things in such a hi -cleaning rings. I can not export . Export signed app used 'm saying in my next button is not an emergency . Application Type exported can not be due to the error (s) below gives error

Answer (score 0):

```html
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder line 431 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder line 430 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 192 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder line 371 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder line 362 Java Problem
    layout cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 64 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder line 216 Java Problem
    layout cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 125 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder line 195 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder line 155 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/projects/storefinder line 154 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 178 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 180 Java Problem
    layout cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 48 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field MGUtilities.java /StoreFinder/src/com/utilities line 118 Java Problem
    layout cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 105 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field MGUtilities.java /StoreFinder/src/com/utilities line 115 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field MGUtilities.java /StoreFinder/src/com/utilities line 100 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field LoginActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 173 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 157 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 159 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field LoginActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 172 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field LoginActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 98 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 171 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field LoginActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 83 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field LoginActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 79 Java Problem
layout cannot be resolved or is not a field CategoryFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 37 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field LoginActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 64 Java Problem
    layout cannot be resolved or is not a field CategoryFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 83 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field LoginActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 61 Java Problem
    layout cannot be resolved or is not a field AnimationFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 24 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field LoginActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 58 Java Problem
    layout cannot be resolved or is not a field AboutUsFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 24 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field ImageViewerActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 124 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field AboutUsFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 58 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field AboutUsFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 61 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field AboutUsFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 65 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 17 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 392 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 384 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 18 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 373 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 332 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 19 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 329 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 305 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 20 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 290 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 270 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 21 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 258 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 254 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 22 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 251 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 234 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 23 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 218 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field HomeFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 208 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 24 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 200 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 197 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 25 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 185 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 182 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 26 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 166 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 163 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 27 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 138 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FeaturedFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 120 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 29 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 176 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 173 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 32 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 33 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 34 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 164 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 161 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 10 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 10 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 145 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 15 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 142 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 117 Java Problem
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field UIConfig.java /StoreFinder/src/com/config line 16 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field FavoriteFragment.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments line 101 Java Problem
    id cannot be resolved or is not a field DetailActivity.java /StoreFinder/src/com/fragments/activity line 983 Java Problem
    The type R is already defined R.java /StoreFinder/gen/com/projects/storefinder line 10 Java Problem
```